# How to get a result with three characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get a value of column with three characters instead of one.

this is my request : `select rank() over (order by 1,2,32 ) from dual`

and these is the result :

[image]

I need to get `001` instead of `1`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`LPAD()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2017.htm):

```
SELECT LPAD( '1', 3, '0' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

```
001
```

So wrapping it around your query:

```
SELECT LPAD( rank() over (order by 1,2,32 ), 3, '0' )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Comment: Yes Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most straight-forward solution:

```
select to_char(rank() over (order by 1,2,32 ),'fm000') from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, You can use `SUBSTR()` like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('000' || CAST((RANK() OVER (ORDER BY 1,2,32)) AS VARCHAR(3)), -3, 3) 
FROM DUAL;
```

Not tested yet ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
select lpad(rank() over (order by 1,2,32 ),3,0) from dual;

select substr('00' || rank() over (order by 1,2,32 ),1,3) from dual;
```